# Sorting a linked list by string

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to sort a linked list and keep getting "no suitable method found for sort(LinkedList,>). What am I doing wrong?

```
public Contributor(String firstName, String lastName, String city,
            String country, String phone, double contribution, int id) {
        // CONSTRUCTOR WITH ALL ATTRIBUTES PASSED
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.contribution = contribution;
        this.id = id;
    }

public static LinkedList<Contributor> contributorList = new LinkedList<>();



Collections.sort(contributorList, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What type is contributorList?

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `contributorList`?

Comment: Then you should have `Comparator<Contributor>`.

Comment: pls post Contributor class. attribute you want to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort using comparator by comparing Contributor objects.

```
Collections.sort(contributorList, new Comparator<Contributor>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contributor o1, Contributor o2) {
       return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1.lastname, o2.lastname);
    }
});
```